# Why SVG file does not change scale in Java?

Tags: java, svg, javafx

I have a SVG file and I'm trying to integrate it within a button using javafx, I succeed in that but it keeps a big size, at the begging the file was like this

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M8 256c0 137 111 248 248 248s248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8 8 119 8 256zM256 40c118.7 0 216 96.1 216 216 0 118.7-96.1 216-216 216-118.7 0-216-96.1-216-216 0-118.7 96.1-216 216-216zm-32 88v64H120c-13.2 0-24 10.8-24 24v80c0 13.2 10.8 24 24 24h104v64c0 28.4 34.5 42.8 54.6 22.6l128-128c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.8 0-45.3l-128-128c-20.1-20-54.6-5.8-54.6 22.7zm160 128L256 384v-96H128v-64h128v-96l128 128z"/></svg>
```

so I thought I've to change its scale, so I add a specific width and height

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="150px" height="150px">...
```

I've used SVGLoader from [git](https://github.com/skrb/SVGLoader), and I wrote this code to see the results

```
package tutoFX;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import net.javainthebox.caraibe.svg.SVGContent;
import net.javainthebox.caraibe.svg.SVGLoader;

public class SVGLoaderSample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        SVGContent content = SVGLoader.load(getClass().getResource("arrow-alt-circle-right10.svg").toString());

        // create a button and set the graphics node
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setGraphic(content);

        // add the button to the scene and show the scene
        HBox layout = new HBox(button);
        HBox.setMargin(button, new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("SVGLoader Sample");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXLek.jpg)

but not as expected, some of you might say use this

```
        // Scale the image and wrap it in a Group to make the button 
        // properly scale to the size of the image  

        content.setScaleX(0.1);
        content.setScaleY(0.1);
```

Yes it changes the size of the icon, but it keeps the node bigger
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av0i9.jpg)

thanks for help

Comment: *Yes it change the size but it keeps the node bigger* - use a smaller scale value. The original svg file is a 496x496px path inside a 512x512px box, so dimensions are correct. If you don't want to change the original file and scale it,you'll have to scale it programmatically with `setScaleX` and `setScaleY`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I advise you to use `import javafx.scene.Group;`

```
package tutoFX;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import net.javainthebox.caraibe.svg.SVGContent;
import net.javainthebox.caraibe.svg.SVGLoader;

public class SVGLoaderSample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        SVGContent content = SVGLoader.load(getClass().getResource("arrow-alt-circle-right10.svg").toString());
        // Scale the image and wrap it in a Group to make the button 
        // properly scale to the size of the image  

        content.setScaleX(0.1);
        content.setScaleY(0.1);
        Group graphic = new Group(content);
        // create a button and set the graphics node
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setGraphic(graphic);

        // add the button to the scene and show the scene
        HBox layout = new HBox(button);
        HBox.setMargin(button, new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("SVGLoader Sample");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: but I can't understand why ?